# ComboBox Change order of Elements

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a few ideas of implementing the task, that is of changing the order of the items that appear in the dropdownmenu of a combobox. As of now I am using the multiselect property of an open file dialog to populate given files into the combobox. As of now the items are automatically sorted in alphabetical order. Ideally, this is not what a user wants or needs for the type of application I am accomplishing.

So here are a few of my questions/ideas:

1) Maybe the more simple idea is instead of having the files be sorted alphabetically, instead have them sorted by order of click? Is this possible?

2) On each item on the dropdown menu on the right side, add a small up/down arrow, so when clicked the order of the items change. I can easily implement the logic for this idea, but I am not so sure how to add the visuals.

3) Drag and Drop.. I know this tends to be easier in a textbox, but is there a simple way to accomplish it with a dropdown menu.

4) Maybe a simple Ctrl+Up+Click/Ctrl+Down+Click. I feel like I can implement this, but am still not sure if I would be doing it so correctly.

I ask for suggestions from the stackoverflow community, because obviously for one, much of you have more experience in C# than me, so if I can save some time and effort, it would really help accomplish my task. Obviously I'm not asking for code, just some suggestions. Thank You.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a List<string> and using the Sort Method on that List<T> then binding it to the ComboBox?

Comment: No, because that's not really what I'm looking for. I want to know which event in the UI framework would be best to trigger the logic. For example, Drag and Drop --> Switch order of Dragged element with element it's dropped under.

Comment: you should get familiar with using `Collections` it doesn't matter if it's filled or not you can always manipulate the collection depending on where in the `Event Chain` you want to trigger the code.. you are making this simple task a bit more difficult than it needs to be.. i.e `Don't over think the process` `KISS` Method works wonders... `KEEP IT SIMPLE`

Comment: So lets say the List is binded to the Combobox. Which event would you suggest to trigger the manipulation of the collection?

Comment: Where in your process do you want to alter the Collection.. I would also recommend using a BindingList as well you tell me where you want it.. I am not doing the program you are..

Comment: Once the list is populated in the comboBox, I'd like to be able the change the order of the list when the user chooses to do so. That's why I asked in the question which method was more efficient for the programmer to handle the users wish. For example, the user pulls down the dropdown menu, holds down one element and drags it below another element. The list then gets resorted. Another idea is using a simple button that is on each textfield in the drop down menu, and when clicked, the element moves up one spot in the list or down. Basically I want to know the more efficient approach.

Comment: sorry I have no time at the moment to discuss in chat room I am busy

Answer (score 1):

I would always use an underlying collection, such as List or List.
When changing the order, you first change the collection and then assign the List to your UI control.

To change at runtime, you can "refresh" the control by removing and re-adding items.
In my example, I've used Listbox in a Winforms project:

```
//Default fill
List<string> Values = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
Values.ForEach(i => listBox1.Items.Add(i));
//After a while, we sort the list
Values.Sort();
listBox1.Items.Clear();
Values.ForEach(i => listBox1.Items.Add(i));
```

Or, through datasource:

```
//Default fill
Values = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
listBox1.DataSource = Values;
//After a while, we sort the list
Values.Sort();
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = Values;
```

Comment: What if I wanted to change the order during runtime. I have the combobox already populated and I need some time of event to occur in order to change the order. Like I said, I won't have much trouble changing the logic underlying. All I'd have to do is change the index of the elements in my filenames string array.

Comment: @user1819301 I have edited my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I know how to sort a list. I'm trying to enable the ability, for a user to manually change the order of the comboBoxitems through GUI components. I just don't know which is the most efficient to implement